# When creating a UIGestureRecognizer, why does its action use a #selector?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, selector

Take this code, for example.

```
    let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(
        target: self, action: #selector(SomeClass.someFunction)
```

Why is the action `#selector(MyClass.function)`? Why can't it just be `MyClass.function` without the selector wrapping?

Comment: This has to do with legacy code and Objective-C. The API was designed when there was Objective-C and it uses message sending paradigm. ``objc_msgSend```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#selector` is just wrapper on function that check syntactics. It test only if method you declare exist in your code. This way you will avoid errors like typo in Objective-C selector strings.

You can't pass pointer to func as you suggest because under hood selectors works in little other way then call method.

I think it works like perform selector on target, not simply invoke selector method.

You can avoid using class name in `#selector`. Pass `#selector(yourMethod)` or `#selector(yourMethodWithParam(_:))` is also valid.

Comment: You can bypass class name only if you declare `Selector` for method existed in `self`.

Answer (score 0):

From `UIGestureRecognizer` doc:

```
public init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) // designated initializer
```

So It's clear that `action` will be `Selector` type thats why you have to write `#selector(SomeClass.someFunction)`

Answer (score 0):

To tackle simple typos that could easily introduce bugs, Swift 2.2 deprecates using strings for selectors and instead introduces new syntax: #selector.

See:- 
https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/
(Compile-time checked selectors)